# Se pueden recuperar varias matrices del controlador a través de ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Intenté esto:

```
public function veras() {
    $guia = Guide::all();
    $pro = Product::all();
    // return response(json_encode(array('guia'=>$guia,'pro'=>$pro)),200)->header("Content-type', 'text/plain');
}
```

Así intenté llamarlo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{route('veras')}}",
    data: "data",

    success: function (response) {
        var cantidades = JSON.parse(response.guia);
        var pro = JSON.parse(response.pro);
    }
});
});
```

Soy nuevo y la verdad no sé cómo devolver varias matrices desde ajax o si es que no se puede hacer eso.

Comment: Explica más... ¿"varios arreglos"? ¿En qué sentido? ¿Tienes un array de URLs y quieres hacer peticiones a todas esas URLs? ¿Tienes en la respuesta (`response`) un array?

Comment: Hola @luisAlbertoAlbarranJara, en la comunidad no suelen ser bien vistas las preguntas con imágenes de código, pues obligas a quien quiera responderte y probar tu código el tener que escribirlo todo desde cero. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y sustituyas las imágenes por el código real pegado como texto. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lo primero: **preferimos que copies y pegues las cosas en el texto de la pregunta que usar capturas de pantalla**. Para continuar, lo que pides es muy sencillo (redactando respuesta).

Answer (score 1):

Tu código va por buen camino, pero le queda identificar el tipo de dato devuelto para que jQuery sea capaz de hacer la conversión adecuada.

Envías una cabecera `Content-type` con valor `text/plain`, que provoca que jQuery devuelva el valor devuelto por la llamada como una cadena de caracteres (`String`) en el primer parámetro de la retrollamada (`response`).

Para que jQuery haga la traducción de JSON a datos nativos de JavaScript debes enviar la cabecera `Content-type` con el valor `application/json`.

Para ello el código de tu controlador debería quedar tal que así:

```
public function veras() {
    $guia = Guide::all();
    $pro = Product::all();
    return response(
        json_encode(
            array(
                'guia' => $guia,
                'pro' => $pro,
            )
        ),
        200
     )->header("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
}
```

Tu código JavaScript queda casi igual, pero ya no es necesario hacer uso de `JSON.parse()` porque jQuery hizo la conversión adecuada:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{route('veras')}}",
        data: "data",
        success: function (response) {
            var cantidades = response.guia;
            var pro = response.pro;
        }
    });
});
```

---

También podrías haber forzado en el lado de jQuery la conversión que debía realizarse mediante el uso del parámetro [`dataType`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (también sería innecesario hacer `JSON.parse()`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{route('veras')}}",
        data: "data",
        dataType: "json", /* Forzamos la interpretación del resultado como JSON */
        success: function (response) {
            var cantidades = response.guia;
            var pro = response.pro;
        }
    });
});
```

---

Por último, también podrías haber convertido la cadena de caracteres que te entregó jQuery a datos nativos de JavaScript haciendo uso de [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{route('veras')}}",
        data: "data",
        success: function (response) {
            const datos = JSON.parse(response);
            var cantidades = datos.guia;
            var pro = datos.pro;
        }
    });
});
```

Pero como puedes ver he aplicado `JSON.parse()` a la cadena de caracteres que me ha devuelto el servidor. Una vez hecho tenemos disponibles los datos igual que antes.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, usé la primera forma en la llamada desde ajax en jquery, y ya no me sale error, ahora el único problema esque si detecta la cantidad de objetos, pero solo trae los sin los datos, es decir me vota objetos vacios, pero con la cantidad que si es la precisa... así : cantidades = [ ],[ ],[ ],[ ]

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código te pasa eso? ¿Podrías explicar mejor paso a paso qué haces para reproducir tu problema? No entiendo en qué zona del código el número de objetos entregado es variable. ¿Te refieres a los contenidos de `guia` y `pro`?